# Restful API to get user behavior without session and cookie

Tags: rest, session, cookies

Restful API requires us to use token as authentication tool rather than use cookies. Additionally, it's better not use any cookie or session. So how can we record user behavior history like what he buys on shopping chart to recommend similar product for next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use cookies, either use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or store it server-side in a database.

Comment: So in these cases, local storage is like cookies in client side and server-side database is like sessions? And that authentication token is like traditional session id?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. For example with [JWT](https://jwt.io/) you can store the token along with its key in a database table on your server, along with a unique id for the user. Then create another table for the behaviour history and include a foreign key to the token table.